Lagrangian error for truncated taylor series of $\tan(x)$
For a taylor series truncated at the $nth$ derivative, I know that we can calculate the lagrangian error of the terms in the tail by applying the following formula:
$$Error = \frac{f^{n+1}(c)}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)^{n+1}$$
Where $c \in (x, x_0)$ and $x_0$ is the point at which the taylor polynomial is centered. With this formula we can attain an upper bound for the error resultant from truncating the taylor series at the term coinciding with the $nth$ derivative.
The problem I am trying to solve is to evaluate the error from truncating the taylor series for $tan(x)$ centered at $0$ with $2$ terms.
$$tan(x) = x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2x^2}{15}+ ...$$
So in essence, I want to find the upper bound on the error for $|tan(x) -x -\frac{x^3}{3}|$. My question comes from the fact that in the taylor polynomial for $tan(x)$, the factorial term in the denominator isn't present like it is with other common taylor series such as $e^x$, $cos(x)$ etc. Can I still use the lagrangian method to find the error with $Error = \frac{f^{4}(0)}{(4)!}(x)^{4}$, or do I have to perform some preliminary manipulations in order to attain the correct result?
I am sorry if this is a trivial question, I am just not well acquainted with estimating the error of taylor series and what I've found online for this particular situation hasn't been very clear.
